# How to move a line having equal distance separation - three parallel lines (3d) case

Tags: c++, math, vector, geometry, computational-geometry

I have three parallel lines (all are 3d lines). say AB, CD, EF. The center line i.e. CD is given by the intersection of two planes by which the AB, DE lie on. The shortest distance between AB and CD (say d1) is not exactly equal to the CD and EF (say d2).

the line which is given a shorter distance from the center line should be replaced by a fourth line, making equal distance separation with the other line.

I know vectors of each line, and also know a 3D point lie on each line as well. (for AB and EF I know another point which lie on lines; meaning AB and EF can be taken as line segments)

I was trying to do it. But cannot figure out exactly and got some wrong answers. sometime fourth line make the separation more shorter (may be the vector is directing other way or I follow some wrong way). I should say that vectors of AB,CD & EF lines are not directing in to same direction.

So, I am looking for a concrete way to do this. I have vector3 and line class to do this in c++.

please anyone show me how to do this b shifting one line (i.e. drawing 4th line). thanks

Comment: Couple of questions: are you using integer or floating point math? Do you understand the limitation implicit in your choice (either aliasing or the simple limits of floating point precision)?

Comment: @dmckee: I am sorry. I didnt get what you are asking. just using my own classes. NO idea about the limitations.. normally d1, d2 differs 10-80 cm.

Comment: Floating point number do not have infinite precision and can not do everything that the mathematical set of the Reals can do. You might goggle for "What every programmer should know about floating point" or look in a randomly selected numeric analysis text.

Comment: @dmckee: sorry i got it. As my lines away bit (say nerly 1 meter) , I want to organise them having eqaul way (say nearly 5cm). in that sense it would be floating point case. But, generally I am looking for how to do this for unequally holding lines to move and make equal way. thanks again.

Comment: If you calculate the distances between the lines, you probably have a vector that is normal to the lines and whose length is the distance. Then all you need to do is setting the base point of AB to `[base point of CD] + [direction] * d2 / d1`. Substituting the `+` with a `-` gives another solution.

Comment: Are your lines all on the same plane ?

Comment: @Synxis: no on 2 difference plane

Comment: @Nico Schertler: thanks for the comments. I didn't get exactly what you said. May be the one I did was equal to your way. If I say what i did is: I found the vector (V) which is perpendicular to the AB by getting cross product of plane normal (its always going +Z direction) & direction of line AB. then got a normalize vector of V. then I multiply it by distance between AB, CD. then add it to base coordinate of AB. But may  be AB is directing opposite way, my new line was more closer to CD. But I always want to shift AB (or EF) away. couldn't get a correct answer. any help plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/247105/35416) your question over at the math stack exchange, as the formula typesetting capabilities over there were very useful for this answer. The core idea is to establish two vectors which point from the central line to each of the other lines, and which are perpendicular to the directions of your lines. Then you can compare the lengths of these vectors, scale the shorter one to the length of the longer one, and use that scaled vector to obtain the new line.